# 404 is not getting completed and hinders the next requests

Tags: .htaccess, magento, http-status-code-404

I have an e-commerce website created using magento. Whenever there is a 404 not found error, the loading of the site stops (or rather it keeps on trying to get that specific resource) and it kind of freezes. Other links or pages are not accessible for some time. I can browse the website only after around a couple of minutes (~5 minutes may be). Below is the screenshot of the firebug 'net' panel. First one while loading. And next after 5 minutes.

[image: firebug loading]

[image: firebug loading complete]

My htaccess is as below, if that has something to do with it.

```
            DirectoryIndex index.php

            <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            php_value memory_limit 8M
            php_value max_execution_time 180
            php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
            php_flag session.auto_start off
            php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
            php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off
            </IfModule>

            <IfModule mod_security.c>
            SecFilterEngine Off
            SecFilterScanPOST Off
            </IfModule>

            <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
            SSLOptions StdEnvVars
            </IfModule>

            <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options +FollowSymLinks
            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteBase /
            RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
            RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
            RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
            RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
            </IfModule>

            AddDefaultCharset Off

            <IfModule mod_expires.c>
            ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
            </IfModule>

            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all

            <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
            </Files>

            ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
            #SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"
```

This happens only when a resource is not found in the page. I'm confused where to look for a solution. Thanks for looking into. Moderators, you may please rephrase the title if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The 404 page template had some images missing. I removed those and it started loading correctly.